# error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’ fix?

Tags: c++, class

I'm working on my assignment to get two xand y coordinates and get their length in a Point.cpp and their slope in a LineSegment.cpp when I try to call my setXCoord in my point class I run into these errors.

LineSegment.cpp: In member function ‘void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point)’:
LineSegment.cpp:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’

```
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1)
{
       p1.setXCoord(double);                        // set first xcoordinate to p1
        p1.setYCoord(double);                   // set first ycoordinate to p1
}
```

LineSegment.cpp: In member function ‘double LineSegment::getEnd1()’:
LineSegment.cpp:35: error: cannot convert ‘Point’ to ‘double’ in return

```
double LineSegment::getEnd1()
{
    return p1;                          // return first set of points
}
```

my Point is in my Point.hpp  class Point set as a double.

```
Point(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0)
{
    XCoord = x;
    YCoord = y;
}
```

Comment: `double` is a *type*, you can't pass it as an argument to a function. You should pass an actual value.

Comment: Your getEnd1() function returns a double, but you are returning p1, which is a Point.  You need to change one part or the other...

Answer (score 0):

The major issue (obviously, as the compiler has already said) is here and only here:

```
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1)
{
       p1.setXCoord(double);                        // set first xcoordinate to p1
        p1.setYCoord(double);                   // set first ycoordinate to p1
}
```

What happens where? You declare a member function `LineSegment::setEnd1` of type `void(Point)`. Now, the `Point` class has a member function called `setYCoord`, whose type is not provided by you.

Now, `double` is a keyword representing the doubly-precise floating point fundamental type. The C++ semantic rules disallow a keyword from being used as an identifier, with a few exceptions, namely `final` and `override`. Thus, both lines calling `Point::setXCoord()` are invalid. If you're attempting to pass a "type argument", then take a look at [templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29).

Otherwise, you should pass a proper value to the function (also known as a `expression` in standardese and compiler theory speak).

You don't provide the source for said function, so I can't do anymore for you with respect to it.

Now, the second error implies that the compiler knows no way to translate a whatever-is-the-type-of-`p1`-here (it's `Point`, no?) into a double. First of all, this makes no logic. A `Point` contains *two* `double`s, so how do you magically convert it into a *single* `double`? You may do some operation on it, and return that operation's result. Anyway, if you insist this makes any logic, you can declare an implicit type-casting member function:

```
class Point {
    // ...

    public:
        // ...

        operator double() {
            // Somehow transform a Point into a double and return that
        }
};
```

I hope this has led some light on you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `setXCord()` and `setYCord(`) functions take `double` type values as paramaters so you need to pass `double` type values into them. What you did is just placed the variable type of the value you were supposed to pass in. In other words, instead of double you need to pass an actual value.